# difference between use and require

Tags: clojure

Can anyone explain the difference between `use` and `require`, both when used directly and as `:use` and `:require` in the `ns` macro?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358149/in-clojure-1-4-what-is-the-use-of-refer-within-require with regard to the ns macro; in clojure 1.4 it's suggested you use :require by preference to :use

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`require` loads libs (that aren't already loaded), `use` does the same *plus* it refers to their namespaces with `clojure.core/refer` (so you also get the possibility of using `:exclude` etc like with `clojure.core/refer`). Both are recommended for use in `ns` rather than directly.

Comment: If I require lib foo, then to use bar in foo, I'd have to write foo/bar every time, right? Why would you want to load a lib in ns but then not refer it into the ns? I guess you might be worried about collisions, and you don't want to bother having to reconcile them, right?

Comment: not having to reconcile collisions is a good point, and more generally there's a programming style which says "namespaces are a honking great idea, we should have more of them" (from "The Zen of Python") -- so e.g. that style recommends not using "using namespace foo;" in C++, so that readers and maintainers of the code won't have to worry "where does this bar come from" but see a more explicit foo::bar instead.  require (vs use) supports this "explicit namespaces" style.

Comment: Alex gives a good but outdated answer.  As @overthink points out below, after this answer was given idiomatic clojure recommends require over use.  see: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-879

Comment: While this is the accepted and most up-voted answer, it is old and represent an outdated view. The better answer is that from @rzv : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16429572/172272

Answer (score 73):

It's idiomatic to include external functions with `require` and `refer`. You avoid namespace conflicts, you only include functions you actually use/need, and you explicitly declare each function's location:

```
(ns project.core
    (:require [ring.middleware.reload :refer [wrap-reload]]))
```

I do not have to invoke this function by prefixing it with its namespace:

```
(wrap-reload) ; works
```

If you don't use `refer` you'll need to prefix it with the namespace:

```
(ring.middleware.reload/wrap-reload) ; works if you don't use refer in your require
```

If you choose `use` instead, (pretty much) always use `only`:

```
(ns project.core
    (:use [ring.middleware.reload :only [wrap-reload]]))
```

Otherwise you're including everything, making it both an unnecessarily large operation and very confusing for other programmers to find where the functions live.

Also, I highly recommend [this blog](https://8thlight.com/blog/colin-jones/2010/12/05/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns.html) as a resource for learning more about Clojure namespaces.

Comment: Do you know if there is there any difference in the end between `(:use foo :only [bar])` and `(:require foo :refer [bar])`?  Seems odd to have two ways to do this.

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/a/10370672/69689 answers my question.  In short: `(:require .. :refer ..)` is a new way to do the same thing that allows you to effectively deprecate `:use`, which has some drawbacks.

Answer (score 36):

Use sure does make it easier by not requiring you to spell out the namespace every time you want to call a function though it can also make a mess of things by creating namespace conflicts. A good middle ground between "use" and "require" is to only 'use' the functions from a namespace that you actually use.

for instance:

```
 (use '[clojure-contrib.duck-streams :only (writer reader)])
```

or even better, specify it at the top of the file in the namespace definition:

```
(ns com.me.project
   (:use [clojure.contrib.test-is :only (deftest is run-tests)]))
```

Comment: Thanks for including (pun) the `(ns ...)` syntax; I had been looking for that but all the examples I found were for plain `(use ...)`.

Comment: UPDATE: this method has been obsoleted now in favor of `(require '[namepase :refer [var-name1 var-name2]])`

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt You might want to update your answer to include (pun) this.

Answer (score 21):

As has been mentioned the big difference is that with `(require 'foo)`, you then refer to names in the lib's namespace like so: `(foo/bar ...)` if you do `(use 'foo)` then they are now in your current namespace (whatever that may be and provided there are no conflicts) and you can call them like `(bar ...)`.