# Importing clojure functions from jars

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I'm playing around with Clojure, and I can't figure out how to import a function from clojure-contrib.jar. Working from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871997/use-vs-require-in-clojure/1020623#1020623) answer, I'm doing the following:

Running the REPL like so:

```
 java -cp clojure.jar:clojure-contrib.jar clojure.main
```

Then trying to import a function:

```
user=>  (use '[clojure-contrib.duck-streams :only (writer reader)])
```

It doesn't work, and I get the following error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure_contrib/duck_streams__init.class or clojure_contrib/duck_streams.clj on classpath:  (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)

Trying it with a dot instead of a dash also doesn't work:

```
user=>  (use '[clojure.contrib.duck-streams :only (writer reader)])
```

I get mostly the same error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/contrib/duck_streams__init.class or clojure/contrib/duck_streams.clj on classpath:  (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most/all of my problems were from a corrupt jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
(use 'clojure.contrib)
```

I don't have clojure handy right now to check, but

```
(use 'clojure.contrib :only (writer reader))
```

should also work

Comment: I get the following error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/contrib__init.class or clojure/contrib.clj on classpath:  (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)

Comment: I redownloaded clojure-contrib.jar, and it works now. I had a corrupt or unusable jar.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. There is no clojure.contrib namespace, so `(use 'clojure.contrib)` cannot possibly do anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

Is `clojure.jar` and `clojure-contrib.jar` in your current working directory? If not, you need to specify the full path to the JAR files in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: When I tested this exact example, yes they were in my working directory. Specifying their full path doesn't change the error I get though.

Comment: Adding the full path "/usr/lib/clojure-contrib-1.1.0/clojure-contrib.jar" to my CLASSPATH did it for me.  It is the sole thing on my CLASSPATH; not that that should matter.  

I thought jar files would get picked up automatically, I guess I was wrong: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#Setting_the_path_of_a_Jar_file.

Answer (score 0):

It's clojure.contrib, not clojute-contrib. Note dot versus dash.

Comment: Tried that, still didn't work. Updated question to include that test.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Then you have to use `java -cp clojure.jar;clojure-contrib.jar clojure.main` with semicolon instead of colon.

Comment: i cant believe its so hard to run a simple clojure with neccessary jars on ubuntu