# Difference between Use, Require and Import

Tags: clojure

Can any one give me a good example answer to differentiate between Use, Require and Import.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: another duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871997/difference-between-use-and-require?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408076/difference-in-clojure-between-use-and-require?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`require` ensures that a Clojure namespace has been compiled and instantiated.

- optionally updating it from source if provided the `:reload` key
- optionally creating aliases if the `:as` key is provided.
- optionally modifying the current namespace to include mappings to the required namespace's vars, if the `:refer` key is provided. The mapping is only visible from inside the requiring namespace, and is not transitive to other namespaces requiring it.

`use` is identical to require in action, except that the default is to modify the current namespace via the `refer` function to include all the target namespace's vars as if `:refer :all` had been provided. It accepts the `:exclude`, `:only`, and `:rename` keys to guide the modification of the current namespace.

`import` is for adding mappings of Class names to the current namespace, so that the package qualifiers will not need to be used.

Comment: `The mapping is only visible from inside the requiring namespace, and is not transitive to other namespaces requiring it.`

Is `require` otherwise transitive?

Answer (score 1):

In short, use `require`

You'll almost never want to mix-up symbols from different namespaces in the same namespace the way `use` does, except during casual REPL work.

Answer (score 0):

`require` loads and compiles Clojure namespaces. `import` allows you to avoid
using fully-qualified Java class names (the same as `import` in Java).