# clojure with mysql and java

Tags: java, clojure

Not sure why I get this error when I try the code below to execute a query on a MySQL database from clojure:

```
user=> (mysql.core/list-users)

ClassNotFoundException mysql.core  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:366)
```

Here is my project.clj file

```
(defproject mysql "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "FIXME: write description"
:url "http://example.com/FIXME"
:license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
        :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
:dependencies [
                    [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                    [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.3"]
                    [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.25"]
                    [postgresql/postgresql "8.4-702.jdbc4"]
                    [org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc "3.7.2"]
                    [java-jdbc/dsl "0.1.0"]
])
```

Here is my core.clj file

```
(ns mysql.core
 (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]))

(def db {:classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     :subprotocol "mysql"
     :subname "//localhost:3306/dummy"
     :user "idf"
     :password "pwd"})

(defn list-users []
  (sql/with-connection db
  (sql/with-query-results rows
  ["select * from user"]
  (println rows))))
```

HERE IS SOMETHING THAT WORKS (the only thing is you have to get the deps correct without a project file):

```
$ mysql -u root
  mysql> create database clojure_test;
  grant all on clojure_test.* to clojure_test@localhost identified by "clojure_test”;
  use clojure_test;
  CREATE TABLE fruit (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(20),      appearance VARCHAR(20), cost DECIMAL(13,2));

lein repl
user=> (require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as j])
user=> (def mysql-db {:subprotocol "mysql" :subname "//127.0.0.1:3306/clojure_test" :user "clojure_test" :password "clojure_test"})
user=> (j/insert! mysql-db :fruit {:name "Apple" :appearance "rosy" :cost 24} {:name "Orange" :appearance "round" :cost 49})
user=> (j/query mysql-db ["select * from fruit where appearance = ?" "rosy"] :row-fn :cost)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you run code in the repl, you need change to the namespace and load file:

1, Change the repl's namespace by  `(ns mysql.core)`
2, run `(load-file path-to-file)`

EDIT:

another solution is to excute `(use 'mysql.core)` in the repl, then you can run your code.

Comment: I apologize I am very new to Clojure. Do you mean run (ns mysql.core) after I get the user=> prompt? Also, I don't understand step 2?

Comment: step 2 means that you need to load your Clojure file into the context,in your example seems to run `(load-file "src/mysql/core.clj")`

Comment: in `user` namespace you can also use `(use 'mysql.core)`, also edited the answer

Comment: Ok now I get: CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: sql/with-connection, compiling:(/Users/idf/Documents/clojure/mysql/src/mysql/core.clj:11:3)

Comment: `with-connection` is in `clojure.java.jdbc.deprecated`. See http://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc.deprecated

Comment: Gotcha. This may seem like a silly question, but how do I access the deprecated parts of clojure.java.jdbc? I did this, but it did not work :require [clojure.java.jdbc.deprecated] FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/java/jdbc/deprecated/as__init.class or clojure/java/jdbc/deprecated/as.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)

Comment: use `(:use ..)` instead, this link contains more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871997/difference-between-use-and-require . Also it is not a good idea to use function in `deprecated` namespace. You can find some examples in https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc

Comment: Thanks. I finally got something going based on your advice. I posted above a very specific sequence of steps so that others can hopefully gain something from it